# How does bash,sh,ps work in linux?

Tags: c, linux, bash, sh

Here is the sample program I wrote to understand the working of execution in terminal
program1.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     int i;
     printf("Checking out linux working details 2\n");
     pid_t pid=fork();
     return 0;

}
```

Now can you please explain the status of bash,ps,sh processes(i.e their pid's etc). Here is the sample run

running:

```
$ ps -l
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000  4496  4488  0  80   0 -  6730 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 bash
0 R  1000  4506  4496  0  80   0 -  3561 -      pts/2    00:00:00 ps

$ gcc program1.c
$ ps -l
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000  4496  4488  0  80   0 -  6730 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 bash
0 R  1000  4513  4496  0  80   0 -  3561 -      pts/2    00:00:00 ps

$ ./a.out
Checking out linux working details 2

$ ps -l
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000  4496  4488  0  80   0 -  6730 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 bash
0 R  1000  4516  4496  0  80   0 -  3561 -      pts/2    00:00:00 ps

$ ./a.out
Checking out linux working details 2

$ ps -l
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000  4496  4488  0  80   0 -  6730 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 bash
0 R  1000  4519  4496  0  80   0 -  3561 -      pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

---

program2.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     system("ps -l");
     return 0;
}
```

sample run:

```
$ ps -l
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000  4592  4584  0  80   0 -  6730 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 bash
0 R  1000  4602  4592  0  80   0 -  3561 -      pts/2    00:00:00 ps

$ gcc program2.c
$ ps -l
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000  4592  4584  0  80   0 -  6730 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 bash
0 R  1000  4609  4592  0  80   0 -  3561 -      pts/2    00:00:00 ps

$ ./a.out
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000  4592  4584  0  80   0 -  6730 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 bash
0 S  1000  4610  4592  0  80   0 -  1055 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 a.out
0 S  1000  4611  4610  0  80   0 -  1119 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 sh
0 R  1000  4612  4611  0  80   0 -  3561 -      pts/2    00:00:00 ps

$ ps -l
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000  4592  4584  0  80   0 -  6730 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 bash
0 R  1000  4613  4592  0  80   0 -  3561 -      pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

ps : A detailed answer would be highly appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you need explained. In example 1, your code exits so fast that `ps -l` doesn't catch the running process. In #2, the only thing that catches it is the `ps -l` running inside the program (aka while it's still running).

Comment: IN first case Why is the pid of ps changed after compilation or execution ?
IN second case , what exactly happens when using system(command) ?

Comment: Each time you run `ps -l`, it's a short lived new process with a new pid.

Comment: But pid of ps changed when gcc is used .. What exactly does the process ps do ? Also what happens when terminal is started ..

Comment: @MysticForce It's not clear what kind of answer you're looking for... Here is the documentation for what ps does: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps  Here, http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/ is the explanation for how a terminal works, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier is the explanation of what a pid is, but it's rather unknown to anyone if that's explaining anything you're asking about.

Comment: There is enough information available for the system commands. stack overflow is no tutorial site. See the man pages and other documentation. Read a book about Linux system administration.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run a program a new process with unique pid is created.
That's the reason why in your examples the pid of bash stays the same all the time, because it is still the same process, and all the consecutive calls of ps have different ones.

You although can see the parent pid (ppid) with "ps -l" which shows you the pid of the process which created it (forked).

Maybe you want to try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
     int i;
     printf("before fork() ps -l\n");
     system("ps -l");
     pid_t pid=fork();
     if (pid < 0) {
          printf("fork-error.");
     } else if (pid == 0) {
          printf("child ps -l\n");
          system("ps -l");
     } else {
          int status;
          pid_t finished = wait(&status);
          printf("parent with child %i finished %i ps -l\n", pid, finished);
          system("ps -l");
     }
     return 0;
}
```